# Enable-Migrations Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a library based on .NET 4.6.2 version.
To the library, I've added the EntityFramework version 6.1.3 package.
I created a model as follow

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Components.Models
{
  public class Session
  {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Identity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And the dbcontext

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using Components.Models;

namespace Components.DataContexts
{
  public class SessionContext : DbContext
  {
    public SessionContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sessiondb"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
    }

  }
}
```

Then I tried to enable migration and did via

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

statement, got the error message:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."At D:\C#\IndustryCloud\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project, Int32 shellVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebProject(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What do I doing wrong?

**Update** 
Here the structure, how projet is build

[image]

In the sessiontest.cs, I wrote the test for db.

```
[Test]
public void InsertARow_DbInitial_ExpectDbValue()
{

  var sn = new Session()
  {
    Identity = Random.Generate(15),
    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
    UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now
  };

  db.Sessions.Add(sn);
  db.SaveChanges();

}
```

The ComponentsTest project, where I wrote the unit test, the app.config looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Session;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" name="sessiondb" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And in the library(Component) itself the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Session;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" name="sessiondb" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Possibly an issue with your startup project? re [Enable-Migrations installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308170/enable-migrations-installation-error)

Comment: I updated my post, please check. What could be wrong with startup project?

Comment: Do you define your connection String correctly?

Comment: I updated my post, please check.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Other answers suggest this is an issue with your startup project.

As your project is a library, you could try setting your unit test project as your startup project per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308170/enable-migrations-installation-error/17366699#17366699).

You could also try setting the default project in Package Manager Console to your library project per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527366/cannot-enable-migrations-for-entity-framework-in-class-library).

You might run into issues with where the migrations are created. If you need further control, in EF6 there are various arguments you can use with `Enable-Migrations` as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126711/enable-migrations-with-context-in-separate-assembly/18128768#18128768) but I don't have enough knowledge in this area to guide you further. You might need to do some reading.

Comment: Juhui it works. I set Components as startup project. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 22):

2018 update - if the accepted answer doesn't help, see [this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/231) on the EF6 repository.
Apparently code migration commands don't work with the new project format. In order for the migrations commands to work, you need to create a `Class Library (.NET Framework)` project (old standard), move all the files there, add all the needed dependencies and run the command.

EDIT: I just ran into this problem by creating a `Class Library (.NET Standard)` project on VisualStudio 2017 15.6.6 using EntityFramework 6.2.0. Creating an "old standard" project as explained above fixes it.

Comment: I had the very same problem with the new SDK format. It was enough to upgrade Entity Framework to version 6.4 (I think anything 6.3+ will work).

Comment: I ran into this last night. My DataAccess project (Visual Studio 2019)t had been created as Standard not the .net Framework type of Class Library.

Comment: I had the same issue updating from 6.1.x to 6.4 helped

Answer (score 15):

To be free from defining startup project explicitly , you can use the command:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName Components -StartupProjectName Components
```

The parameters are:

**-ProjectName**

Specifies the project that the scaffolded migrations configuration class will be added to (configuration.cs). 
        If omitted, the default project selected in package manager
        console is used.

**-StartUpProjectName**

Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If omitted, the specified project's configuration file is used.

To get more details for the command, run:

```
get-help enable-migrations -Full
```

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if you have both Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer installed alongside an older version of EntityFramework say 6.x

In Visual Studio, go to Project/Manage Nuget Packages...

Take a look through the Installed list and if more than one version of EntityFramework is installed, uninstall all older versions, leaving only the latest version.

Comment: The VS project template for ASP.NET Core had installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` which includes `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`. After installing EF6, I got the same error. The solution was to remove the "all" version of the package and re-install the other needed packages separately.

Answer (score 1):

This error occured to me today, after I cloned an old-ish project which was still configured to run on asp.net Core Rc2. After I installed 1.1 and changed all the variables the error persisted.

The solution in my case was to **reboot**. The installation of Asp.net Core 1.1 wasn't finished yet.

Comment: I'm having this issue with ASP.NET Core and a full .NET framework when the migrations are on another class library project. I'll give this update a go.

Comment: @James - did you manage to fix this, I have the same problem but couldnt find a way forward.

Comment: I didn't spend much more time on it, this wasn't a project for production, just me messing around with the changes. I did try to recreate the issue with the released VS2017 and it no longer happens, it all just works.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Simple fix (as stated above) `-StartupProjectName YourEF6ProjectNameHere`

When I had been using the wrong StartupProjectName I still got the error. That's when I was using the solution below:

My kludgy work-around is to unload the project that does not require EF migrations:

1. Unload the startup project (in my case an ASP.Net Core project). Right-click the project name and selecting `Unload Project`.
2. Run the needed migration commands in the Package Manager Console
3. Right-click the unloaded project and choose `Reload Project`
4. Right-click the same project and choose `Set as StartUp Project`.

Not fun.

Answer (score 1):

I also had 2 versions of EF installed and using "EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration [migrationname]" command to specify which version to use solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is using visual studio 2017 then you might have to check for the following packages

Nuget Packages

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

after that run the migrations command below on console

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Enable-Migrations

EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Book
```

Answer (score 0):

run:

**"EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations"**

for Entity Framework 6.
NB: use the version of your package installed.

Begin subsequent commands with: **EntityFramework6**

where **EntityFramework** is the package that has the libraries to perform our command.