# Entity Framework 6.2 in Class Library doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dll

I have the following problem: I tried to put my `DbContext` class into a separate class library, but it doesn't work.

I get the following error:

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
>   At D:\Projekte\Seminar_Tool_Online\Seminar_Tool_Online\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
>   + $domain.SetData('project', $project)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException
>
> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
>   At D:\Projekte\Seminar_Tool_Online\Seminar_Tool_Online\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:721 char:5
>   + $domain.SetData('contextProject', $contextProject)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with the name "Seminar_Tool_Online" this is my start up project. And in the config file is everything Entity Framework needs.

```
<configSections> 
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AccountConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=...; Database=...;User Id = ...; password=...; Integrated Security=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

My class library is called `Seminar_Tool_Datenbank` with the following `DbContext` class:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("AccountConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            } 
    }
```

So I tried it with the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName Seminar_Tool_Datenbank -StartupProjectName Seminar_Tool_Online
```

I have already tried the solutions from here:

- [Enable-Migrations Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436256/enable-migrations-exception-calling-setdata-with-2-arguments)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/840863/Entity-Framework-Migrations-enabled-in-Data-Access

Nothing works for me, I still get the same error. In both projects, I use EF 6.2 and .Net 4.5.1

Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**

Can this be the problem?

[Make EF NuGet package / migrations and EF Tools work with new csproj format](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/231)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem by change the csproj-file to the old standard of VS 2015.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @VinylWarmth I create the project with Visual Studio 2015 and after this I can use it in Visual Studio 2017