# How to change the csproj file back to old format in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, projects-and-solutions

I have the problem when I make a new class library in VS 2017 the csproj file has always the new format but I want the old format

This is the format I get

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

but I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

And how can I stop that VS 2017 do this automatically?

[This would help my by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138120/entity-framework-6-2-in-class-library-doesnt-work)

I hope someone can help me?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to create the project in VS 2015 or prior and after it is created, open the project in VS 2017. That said, it is unclear why anyone would want that *overly verbose* old `.csproj` format that required you to put NuGet information into a separate `.nuspec` file and *add all files explicitly* to the project.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for the answer do you know where I can get VS 2015 on Microsoft website i only find VS 2017?

Comment: @NightOwl888 And the reason why I need the old format is because that migrations with Ef 6.2 don’t work with the new format

Comment: [Download older Visual Studio Software](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thx but when I login on my account it shows 0 results ? Do I need something spezial?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290672/how-to-download-visual-studio-community-edition-2015-not-2017) to see if any of those links help.

Comment: @NightOwl888 As always thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments to solve the problem i create the project in VS 2015 and open it with VS 2017